# My Uninstall of Ubuntu 14.04 from Windows 8.1 messed up using EasyBCD

Tags: boot, windows-8, lenovo

I started with a pre-installed Windows 8.1 Lenovo with one-key recovery. I dual booted Ubuntu. Then I uninstalled Ubuntu to reinstall again in a better way. I was trying to boot with windows 8 boot manager instead of GRUB. something messed up and now I always get a screen that says:

```
    GNU GRUB version 2.02-beta29ubuntul

    Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, .....ect.

    grub>
```

So, I tried

```
    grub> exit
```

It goes into Boot Manager with a Boot Option Menu 
but the only option is

```
    ubuntu <WDC WD10JPCX-24UET0>
```

there is no Windows Option most probably because this is the wrong partition and it is not reading the NTFS partition.

I tried

```
    grub>ls
```

and everything had

```
    <hd0, ...>
```

so Ubuntu is corrupt/ uninstalled

I do not have a windows installation disk.

```
  crtl + alt + del just reboots into the same problem.
```

this whole problem started when I pressed the one-key to boot from USB to install Ubuntu again otherwise it was booting into Windows fine. But now it cannot find it.

I know my Windows 8.1 is there just not accessible on this wrong partition. 
How do I get back into windows boot manager and boot into Windows 8.1?
Or how do I get into the NTFS partition?
Just anything that might work is appreciated.
Please help! Thank you!

Comment: Did you have Ubuntu in BIOS mode, Windows only boots in UEFI mode. Check UEFI settings and turn on UEFI mode, or turn off BIOS/CSM/Legacy mode. Windows should boot with secure boot on or off. Otherwise from Ubuntu live installer in terminal post this: `sudo parted -l`

Comment: Any feed-back do far? Can you boot a LiveCD and post a screenshot of gparted?

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to fix GRUB first:**

I had this happen to me once when I "broke" GRUB. Here's how you can boot from the GRUB terminal:

http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/776643-how-to-rescue-a-non-booting-grub-2-on-linux/

After you get into Ubutnu, you can fix GRUB by installing and running boot-repair:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get install boot-repair
sudo boot-repair
```

Then select the recommended fix.

**If you want to skip GRUB and boot into your windows partition:**

Go into your computer setup and change your boot order to boot from Windows partition first by pressing F2, ESC, or whichever button it is for your board.

**Alternatively**

Having installed, reinstalled, and rearranging partitions all day for the past few days, here's what I found the easiest way to do it. ***NOTE:* THIS WILL WIPE ALL DATA FROM YOUR UBUNTU PARTITION, SO MAKE A BACKUP.**

Boot from a live installation disk and run gparted. (Unmount your hard disk if it's mounted) Delete the Ubutnu partition(s) and create new partition(s) how you want to arrange them. Hit "Apply", exit the application, and run the installer. Select "Other" as the method you'd like to install Ubuntu, then choose your partition(s).

Comment: I have Lenovo so after I took battery out then put it back in I was able to get into BIOS with One key. Then I just chose the system recovery option it worked. Everything is working now. Thank you so much though!